# Browning aloe leaves - what do I do?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, aloe

My aloe plant is currently browning a little. I reported it about six weeks ago into a cactus and succulent mix. I separated some of the aloe pups to grow, they’re currently doing something similar to this problem also. I’ve attached a picture of the leaves below. Any ideas? I’ve had it in a warm area, in indirect sunlight and been watering the main plant infrequently.

Ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you know what type of Aloe this is?  How long have you had it?  Where are you located?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are, but if you are in the northern hemisphere it's likely that your plants are winding down for the year. As long as the browning is on the oldest leaves, it's probably normal shedding of excess leaves. They don't shed, they just dry up.

Have you watered it since you repotted it? I would be very light with the water until the spring-time (again assuming hemisphere).

The coloration can also be from the stress of repotting. I don't see anything in the pictures that would alarm me.

Good luck.